# UItable header always show when scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

My applicaton contains UITableView and show data from SQLite.I want to do this UITableView's header always show when user scrolling the tableview.How to implement it?

Comment: Just put that View outside and top of the `UITableView`. and resize the UITableView to the remaining place.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a view to the view hierarchy above UITableView or - if you use UITableViewController - add the view as subview to UITableView and reposition it in the method `scrollViewDidScroll:` method